# What will be the output of this code and can you explain the step by step progression?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, char

I tried this code and got the output below. But I don't understood how it came.
What is the logic involved in this snippet of code? Can you explain?
Also when ++i is replaced by i++ it gives different output??

```
int main() 
{  
  char i= 0;
  for(i<=5 && i>=-1;++i;i>0) 
    printf("%d\n",i); 
  printf("\n"); 

return 0; 
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 .... 126 127 -128 -127 .... 2 1.
```

Comment: Condition was comparing with the character.[Check this image](https://www.w3resource.com/w3r_images/python-basic-image-exercise-86.png)

Comment: Loop termination condition for the `for` loop is `++i` i.e until `i` not become zero, it will iterate & `printf` gets executes, When `i` become zero in condition part, it comes out from loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is because of the for loop you have written

```
for(i<=5 && i>=-1;++i;i>0)
```

the first option in for loop is executed once. it doesn't check whether the condition is true or not, nor doesn't control the loop execution. even though the expression evaluated to 0, the loop starts executing.
the second part is executed every time the loop begins, and it is the loop breaking condition. that is, if this expression results 0, it breaks.

the third section executes every time, again, doesn't affect the loop execution.

NOw let's analyze your code.
i is initialized to 0 before entering the loop.
initializer in for loop does a condition check, `i<=5 && i>=-1` but doesn't change the value of i.
the condition section does an increment to the variable i, which happens every time it enters the loop. so the value goes from 0,1,2,..127,-128,-127...-1 ( since it is **signed char** which ranges from -128 to 127) and then reaches 0, which means false. when it evaluates to 0, the for loop breaks. thus the output you got.
the 3rd section is again a condition, which doesn't update the value.

you might want to check the syntax of loop, and what is the output you are expecting.

Answer (score 2):

This is what the C standard says about `for` loops:

> The statement for
>
> ( clause-1 ; expression-2 ; expression-3 ) statement
>
> behaves as follows: The expression expression-2 is the controlling
>   expression that is evaluated before each execution of the loop body.
>   The expression expression-3 is evaluated as a void expression after
>   each execution of the loop body. If clause-1 is a declaration, the
>   scope of any identifiers it declares is the remainder of the
>   declaration and the entire loop, including the other two expressions;
>   it is reached in the order of execution before the first evaluation of
>   the controlling expression. If clause-1 is an expression, it is
>   evaluated as a void expression before the first evaluation of the
>   controlling expression.

The `for` loop starts printing with `i` equal to `1`. `i` wraps around after reaching the max value possible for the `char` datatype. The loop terminates when expression-2 i.e. `++i` in this case is `0`. `++i` evaluates to `0` when `i` is `-1`.

Also note that overflowing a signed number results in undefined behaviour. The `char` data type may be signed or unsigned based on your system.

Comment: You said loop terminates when i is equal to -1. But why don't it terminates when i is 6 and greater?

Comment: Because "expression-2", which is `++i` is this case, is the controlling expression that is evaluated before each execution of the loop body. This expression has to be evaluated to `0` for the loop to terminate.

Comment: I get it that ++i had to be evaluated to 0 in order for the loop for terminate but what I'm asking is why it isn't evaluated to 0 when the value of i becomes 6, which is in contradiction with the first condition which is i<=5 && i>=-1.

Comment: The first clause is *not* responsible for validating whether the loop will execute or not and the first clause is executed only *once*. Please re-read the quoted text in my answer.

Comment: Okh I got this one. But how come `++i` evaluates to 0 when i is -1?